# PostgreSQL Ruby Heroku Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, activerecord, heroku

This search condition works fine in MySQL, and SQLite but fails in PostgreSQL:

CONTROLLER:

```
@inventories = Inventory.search(params[:search], params[:page])
```

MODEL:

```
def self.search
paginate    :per_page => 10,
            :page => page, 
            :conditions => ['part_number = ? OR item LIKE ? OR catalognumber LIKE ?', "#{search}", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"],
            :order => 'item'
end
```

IT produces this error in HEROKU's PostgreSQL log:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
2011-06-11T20:25:46+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT * FROM "inventories" WHERE (part_number = E'' OR item LIKE E'' OR catalognumber LIKE E'')  ORDER BY item LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0):
```

How can I fix this?

**SOLUTION**... This is an issue of using LIKE rather than ILIKE
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: Tip: use ILIKE instead of LIKE so your searches are not case-sensitive on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, one of those fields is expecting an integer, and Postgres is a lot less permissive on this front than MySQL. I shouldn't have any quotes. (It should be zero, or no field at all, instead.)

Comment: Part Number is an integer. The rest are strings

Comment: Cast it: part_number = cast(? as int)

Comment: adding search.to_i, fixes the error. But I have no capacity to search for strings. For instance say i search "Item"... search isn't working.

Comment: I was actually meaning in your sql statement, just as above.

Comment: That said, I don't know much about ruby (yet: learning...), so I might be getting the RoR/Active Record thing all wrong, i.e. take it with a pinch of salt. :-)

Comment: it was an issue of using LIKE rather than ILIKE. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html